# Why link not filling li element even though display:block?

Tags: css, hyperlink, superfish

I am using superfish menu and I am having a problem which I can't figure out although I'm sure the answer is probably obvious and I'm just missing it...

Basically my a elements are not expanding to fill their containing li elements, even though the a elements are set to display:block

Please see example here:

http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/fpatest/index_hover2.html

css is here:

http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/fpatest/css/superfish.css

http://www.spiritlevel.co.uk/fpatest/css/superfish-vertical.css

Here's the relevant HTML

```
<div id="homenav">

<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu sf-vertical">

<li id="company"><a href="*">COMPANY</a>
 <ul id="companymenu">
<li id="profilelink"><a href="*">Profile</a></li>
<li id="activitylink"><a href="*">Activity</a></li>
<li id="strategylink"><a href="*">Strategy</a></li>
<li id="teamlink"><a href="*">Team</a></li>
    <li id="financelink"><a href="*">Finance &amp; Governance</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>

<li id="development"><a href="*">DEVELOPMENT</a>
  <ul id="developmentmenu">
<li id="partnerslink"><a href="*">Development Partners</a></li>
<li id="sociallink"><a href="*">Social Responsibility</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

  <li id="projects"><a href="*">PROJECTS</a></li>
  <li id="contact"><a href="*">CONTACT US</a></li>

 </ul>
</div><!--end homenav -->
```

A second issue I am having is how to get the second level menu to appear in the same place for each first level link. If you hover over company then it's 2nd level nav appears in the right place. But if you hover over development, it appears 1 row too low - i would like it to appear in the same place as the company menu did

Can anyone help me out with this please? thanks

Comment: the A elements are expanding for me (on chrome 16 and IE8)... a demo page for everyone to play around with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/4ctDe/

Comment: links seem fine to me too. Also, the 2nd level menu is appearing alongside the link you're currently hovering over because you are nesting the list inside the li's - which is exactly how it's meant to work.

Comment: Just want to thank everyone for taking the time to help and apologise for not responding to this thread earlier. Shortly after writing it I was unfortunately called away to a family emergency which kept me away from work for a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove padding-right from .sf-menu a.sf-with-ul (superfish.css line-93) and add width 100% or 140px (home.css line 75) in #nav li a. I've tested it on your site and works fine. Tested in chrome and ff.

Comment: Thanks - the width on #nav li a was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your links aren't expanding to fill the box is because they are floated left. Remove that and you should be fine.